# Quicker way to calculate RSA private key in PHP

Tags: php, rsa, private-key

Hi I am required to do my own implementation of the RSA algorithm in php. The only thing I have a problem with is the part that calculates the private key. The way my function works is by getting a random number and checking to see if it fits into the private key formula. This works fine, however the only problem is that when using very large numbers, it takes ages and the page times out. I was wondering, is there a better way that I can implement this without having to keep generating random numbers? Here is the required code:

```
$decrypt = rand(1,($phi-1));
while(!private($decrypt, $encrypt, $phi)){
$decrypt = rand(1,($phi-1));
}

...

function private($decrypt, $encrypt, $phi) {

 if(($decrypt * $encrypt) % ($phi) == 1){
 Return true;
 }
 else{
 Return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach will not work. PHP numeric types are double-precision floating point numbers, and as such cannot represent integers exactly beyond around 53 bits. You will most likely need to use a PHP multiprecision library such as [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [gmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php). This will still not be fast, but it will at least give correct results.

Comment: I am limiting the numbers so that they are below the max integer value. The first two prime numbers in the algorithm (p and q) are restricted so that they dnt go beyond the max value. As a result of this, the rest of the algorithm is within the limits. The problem is just finding a quicker way to work out the private key

Comment: Even if `p` and `q` are both within the allowable range, `p * q` may not be, and the overflow will cause precision to be lost.

Comment: Sorry I didnt make myself clear - p and q are within the limits so that even p *q would stay within the limit (only just)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

You'd be better of doing this sequentially. Your rand() can find numbers that have been used previously. Let's say your max is 10, the requred number is 8 or 4, with rand() you could get 3,5,9,10,3,6,2,7,3,6,9,10,1,3,5,6,3,7,8 before hitting an answer. If you run sequentially, you have a max of 10 calls to get it.

But, you need a random number, so you probably should start at a random number, then increase sequentially until you get a hit - that way you could get 8, or you could get 4, depending on your start point.

Option 2:

After that, there are other solutions you can mathematically do. Start with a random number, work out what the modulus is, and the difference from 1 (if negative, add `$phi`). Then you can run from 1 to `$decrypt` to find out what number modded gives teh difference from 1, and then add that to encrypt for your response.

```
$decrypt = 7
$encrypt = 9
$phi = 3
($decrypt * $encrypt) % ($phi) = 0
$differenceInMod = 1 - ($decrypt * $encrypt) % ($phi) = 1;
if ($differenceInMod < 0) {
    $differenceInMod+=$phi;
}
for($i = 1; $i<$decrypt; $i++) {
   if (($decrypt * $i) % ($phi) == $differenceInMod) {
      $validEncrypt = $encrypt + $i;
      break;
   }
}
```

Probably no faster that stright sequential (option 1) - but numbers are smaller and you have limits.

Comment: Is there another formula that I can use to calculate the private key - as im pretty sure theres a mathematical way around it that doesnt require random numbers

Comment: Yes - the reason for the second example is that you can take it further to get $i. But It's not simple, and I've never tried it. A little light reading for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm . There's a couple of examples on that page of how you can work out the modulus, and good luck.  Edit: a page that explains it better: http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/exeucalg.html